# (Mono) Mod-mono's versus custom server's limit on number of concurrent requests

Tags: concurrency, mono, tcplistener

I read that Mod-Mono has a limit on the number of concurrent requests determined by:

MonoMaxActiveRequests 20

MonoMaxWaitingRequests 20

http://www.mono-project.com/Mod_mono

If I have a custom .NET server (using tcplistener) running under mono, does it have a similar limit? If yes, where can I change that limit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mod-mono is a apache module to run mono application and `MonoMaxActiveRequests` and `MonoMaxWaitingRequests` are apache directive added by mod-mono. If you use a custom .NET server with tcp listener on port 80 you dont need apache. Because you are doing this directly by .NET. So there will be no mod-mono and no directive.

> does it have a similar limit?

Answer is **NO**

Comment: Ok, the problem is that I have a tcp server listening for silverlight clients on port 4530. On one ubuntu installation I can make max 16 connections and on another I can make 20 connections. I can't find where this limit is coming from.

Comment: I was using mono 2.6.7. Upgrading to 2.10.8 solves the problem.